AbsArgPlot for List (Parallel Computation)
Basically, I have a very complicated function that I'd like to draw using AbsArgPlot. I thought it could speed up if I first use ParallelTable to generate data then use something like ListLinePlot but with AbsArgPlot's feature.
In fact, it's a parametric integral function appearing in calculation of wavepackect scattering in quantum mechanics. I've already speeded up the integral by replace NIntegrate with ParametricNDSolve. For some parameters it works fine, but for other parameters it takes forever.
My code is like
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{g'[Δ] == 
    Evaluate[
     1/Sqrt[2 π] E^(-I (1000 + Δ) t)
         E^(-I (1000 + Δ) x0 - σ^2 \
Δ^2) (2/π)^(1/4) Sqrt[σ]
         Piecewise[{{(E^(
             I (1000 + Δ) x ) - Γ/(\
Γ - I Δ)
               E^(-I (1000 + Δ) x )), 
           x < 0}, {-((
             I Δ)/(Γ - I Δ))
              E^(I (1000 + Δ) x ), 
           x > 0}}] /. {Γ -> 1, 
        x -> (2 π 3/4)/1000 y, 
        x0 -> (2 π 3/4)/1000 (-1000), σ -> 1/(
         Sqrt[2] σk)} /. σk -> 1], g[-6] == 0}, 
  g, {Δ, -6, 6}, {y, t}]

This is a rather simplified version than what I really want to compute, to replace some terms in it with more complicated functions.
AbsArgPlot[g[x, 10][6] /. sol, {x, -2000, 2000}, Filling -> Bottom]


